# What is the current version of windbg

Tags: windbg

can someone tell me what is the current version of windbg? I have the version that was released with the windows sdk 8.1, however I think there maybe an update or more current version out.

Comment: @LexLi c0000005 Exception in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.threads debugger extension

Comment: @LexLi I asked about this exception last week. And the commentators suggested a windbg bug. Can you have a look at that post and let me know your thoughts?

Comment: latest version is part of the Win10 SDK: dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's now WinDbg 1.x, available from [aka.ms/windbg](https://aka.ms/windbg)

Short overview of version numbers in antichronological order:

```
1.x           Most recent version, with the new UI
1.x Preview   "Beta" version with the new UI
10.x          Versions for Windows 10
6.3.>6000     Versions for Windows 8.1
6.2.>6000     Versions for Windows 8
6.1.>6000     Versions for Windows 7
6.13.0009     Version for Windows 7
6.x.<6000     Windows NT ... Windows 7
4.x           Windows NT 4
```

Note that versioning scheme changed quite often.

---

*original answer*

In my opinion you have the latest version of WinDbg at the time of asking the question: 6.3.9600.16384 which comes with [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/bg162891.aspx).

I <strike>am</strike> was maintaining a [list of WinDbg versions](https://web.archive.org/web/20161124004210/http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/windbg-versions/), also trying to include download links and non-official versions as long as I become aware of them.